# Wordpress search should display only products as a dropdown

Tags: wordpress

I am using flatsome theme in wordpress and i want to customize the search which should display only products and not pages or posts in search filter results as a dropdown and should search only products also.

[image: screenshot]

Please refer the screenshot ,red marked area should omitted from search results.Please help me with this

Comment: What have you tried? You can override the code via a WordPress child theme. Please also ref: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-limit-search-results-for-specific-post-types-in-wordpress/

Comment: i tried this code,but did not work.

Comment: i think this code is for default search for wordpress, it is search form in flatsome theme

Comment: Yes, you will need to override the flatsome theme files within your WordPress child theme.

Comment: yes i think it needed search hook to change this feature, i dont know which hook to use

Comment: Look in the theme folder. In your code editor you can search for a specific element in all files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overrule the file `themes/flatsome/inc/extensions/flatsome-live-search/flatsome-live-search.php` in your child theme and remove

```
, 'page'
```

from line 23.

This only removes the pages from your Ajax search though, they still appear on the search results after.